# Как поменять таблицу пользователей без префикса в laravel

Tags: laravel

В конфиге `database.php` для подключения к mysql используется префикс
Как поменять для пользователей таблицу в бд?
Нужно, чтобы таблица пользователей использовалась без префикса
Пробовал так:
В `user.php` прописать -

```
protected $table = 'users';
```

Но он все равно идет к таблице `prefix_users`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вам нужно в database.php создать новое подключение к бд - такое же самое, которое используется сейчас, но без префикса (назовем его mysql_no_prefix). И для модели User указать явно это подключение:

```
protected $connection = 'mysql_no_prefix';
```